# How to create a movie file (avi) using a set of jpeg files in VB?

Tags: vb.net, video

As part of test automation framework building, I need to record the activities done by the user in a video. 
Since i could not find a way to record a video directly in vb, i opted to capture a sequence of screen shots (print screens) and then convert it to a streaming video.

Please suggest a way to do the same.

thanks,
pkrg

Comment: Please suggest any open source tools available with the following APIs like <br>

1. Start, pause,resume and stop recording
2 Restrict the video size to 3 minutes etc.

Comment: Standard Print Screen wont capture the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can just run another program behind your application.
there are several programs like that.

it is not a professional way but easy way to do this... because probably these programs have already optimized their algorithms...

---

making avi with jpegs:

there are such a programs that do this too...

again you can search for it..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screencasting_software loads of great free(and other licenses) stuff here. All of them are going to produce much better results then a flipbook of jpgs...

Answer (score 1):

You can automate [Windows Media Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5691ba02-e496-465a-bba9-b2f1182cdf24&displaylang=en) there are some samples for C# and VB.NET in the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=000a16f5-d62b-4303-bb22-f0c0861be25b&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) to record user activities of your program. It is also open-source.

Comment: I checked it along with other recorders like WeBEX, QuickScreenRecord etc. But none of these provide apis to 

1. Start,pause,resume, stop recording
2. Restrict the recording to a maximum of 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to roll your own, then

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=161299

Shows several ways to call windows api, to caputure the screen or parts of. Still I think you will have problems with the mouse cursor though. After capturing the screen you will have to draw the cursor in the correct position.